# Disk and Distances

Tags: geometry

Consider a disk $D$ with center $O$ and radius $1$. Choose a point $P$ outside $D$. Is it possible to find three points $A,B,C \in D$ such that the following hold?

- $ |AB|,|BC|,|AC|>1$
- $ |PA|,|PB|,|PC|<1$

I think this is not possible but haven't managed to prove it yet.

Comment: So $P\notin D$ is the only constraint on $P$? Or is $P$ on the edge of $D$? If it's the former, it seems impossible for nearly all $P$.

Comment: Yes , just $P \notin D$.

Comment: It seems like you'd need to determine what subset $P$ can be in for a solution to exist. For example, if $P$ is 2 away from $D$ then there's no point even looking for a solution. If $P$ is on the boundary of $D$ then it seems possible, though.

Comment: We don't allow $P$ to be on the edge of $D$ (so I should probably write "closed disk").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any point $q$, let $B(q,r)$ and $\bar{B}(q,r)$ be the closed/open disk centered at $q$ with radius $r$.

The answer is impossible, we will strengthen the result a little bit.

> For any $P \not\in B(O,1)$, it is impossible to find $a, b, c \in \bar{B}(O,1) \cap \bar{B}(P,1) $ such that $|ab|, |bc|, |ca| > 1$.

Assume the contrary, the intersection $\mathcal{I} \stackrel{def}{=} \bar{B}(O,1) \cap \bar{B}(P,1)$ will be non-empty. Choose a coordinate system
where $O$ is origin and $P$ lies on positive $x$-axis. In this coordinate system $P = (1+\epsilon, 0)$ for some $\epsilon \in [0,1]$. Let $P_0$ be the point $(1,0)$ and $\mathcal{I_0} = \bar{B}(O,1) \cap \bar{B}(P_0,1)$

For any point $q = (x,y) \in \mathcal{I}$, we have

- $x^2 + y^2 \le 1 \implies x \le 1$
- $(x-1-\epsilon)^2 + y^2 \le 1
  \implies (x-1)^2 + y^2 \le 1 + 2\epsilon(x-1) - \epsilon^2 \le 1$

This implies $\mathcal{I} \subset \mathcal{I}_0$. Cut $\mathcal{I}_0$ along  $x$-axis into two pieces. $\mathcal{I}_0 = \mathcal{I}_0^{+1} \cup \mathcal{I}_0^{-}$ where
$$
\mathcal{I}_0^{+} =  \{ (x,y) \in \mathcal{I}_0 : y \ge 0 \}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\mathcal{I}_0^{-} =  \{ (x,y) \in \mathcal{I}_0 : y \le 0 \}
$$
It is easy to see both $\mathcal{I}_0^{\pm}$ can be covered by
[Reuleaux triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle) with
diameter $1$. So their diameter is at most $1$.

For any $3$ points $a,b,c \in \mathcal{I} \subset \mathcal{I}_0$, at least two of them falls into same piece. Let's say $a, b \in \mathcal{I}_0^{+}$, we will get $|ab| \le 1$ because diameter of $\mathcal{I}_0^{+}$ is at most $1$, a contradiction. Same thing happens when $\mathcal{I}_0^{-}$ contains more than two of $a, b, c$.

Combine these, the impossibility follows.